# Changing the Owner of Replication Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, transactional-replication

Just wondering if there is any gotchas with changing the owner of a sql server replication job.  The job owner is currently a domain account, but that person is leaving the company, so the account is soon to be disabled.  I am planning on setting the owner to SA, but wanted to check about the replication jobs first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the owner of a replication job will not impact replication.

Comment: Hey @laxman welcome to [dba.se], got any reference information for people who want to learn more about this?